# CWebUser calling methods from own User model

Tags: authentication, yii

I switched from the default approach to user authentication through LoginForm::authenticate() and login() + SiteController::actionLogin() and actionLogout() to one that uses my app's own User::authenticate() and login() + UserController::actionLogin() and actionLogout().

The User model has other methods (e.g. User::isRegisteredToCourse()) which I need to call very often. Is there an easier, leaner way for the logged User (i.e. the one that has the same ID as the CWebUser) to access those methods than the following...?

```
    User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)->isRegisteredToCourse()
```

I am looking for something like:

```
    LoggedUser::isRegisteredToCourse()
```

Or at least:

```
    Yii::app()->user->isRegisteredToCourse()
```

But I do not know what is the best way to join CWebUser together with my own User model.

Any ideas?

---

**Update:** the simplest way I found to shortcut the reference to the logged User is to create WebUser class extending CWebUser and add this model() method to it that returns a reference to the User:

```
/**
 * Returns the logged user's User model.
 * @return User the user's User model. If the user is not logged in, this will be false.
 */
public function model()
{
    if(count($model=User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)) == 1)
        return $model;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now the invocation of a logged User's method shortens to:

```
    Yii::app()->user->model()->isRegisteredToCourse()
```

Although, I keep looking forward to getting a leaner shortcut as it is not very usable to have to write a five-level reference just to invoke a method from the logged User.

Comment: what is wrong with Yii way? Your approach seems terrible and problematic!

Comment: Hi @Stefano , I am new to yii and am learning the basics with Larry Ullman's Yii Book. He presents two approaches to database user authentication: 1) updating the LoginForm class; or 2) using the existing User model. I decided for the second method since I had a User model already defined and I thought it would be redundant to have User attributes (as well as their rules and labels) duplicated in the LoginForm model.

Anyways, I could step back to the default LoginForm approach, but I do not see that my current issue has to do with the approach followed for user authentication.